# After MySQL change to utf8mb4, Error Unknown character set index for field '224' received from server

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I've changed our server MySQL database to use utf8mb4 because we need to support emoticon. I have followed the instruction based on [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) article by Mathias Bynens. The only difference is I wasn't changing from utf8.

Here's the configuration:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here is MySQL `SHOW VARIABLES` output:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After I restarted MySQL & my application, the console printed the error log as below:

```
2014-08-05 17:33:49,022 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] WARN  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6ae03500 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown character set index for field '224' received from server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getCharsetNameForIndex(Connection.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.<init>(Field.java:192)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackField(MysqlIO.java:731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2076)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1451)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1787)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.loadServerVariables(Connection.java:4478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.initializePropsFromServer(Connection.java:4062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2789)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Aug 5, 2014 5:33:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Aug 5, 2014 5:33:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Aug 5, 2014 5:33:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Aug 5, 2014 5:33:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

Login to my CMS nor API calls don't work. It gave me the above error for which I can't google any solution.

What to do next, in order to fix the error?

Answer (score 8):

I was there too, and I fixed it by simply upgrading the connector to `"mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar"`. Hope it would help.

Download latest connector from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Thanks. You saved my life as well in 2020